# Inspecting apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to do something simple with apache mod_rewrite. And guess what, it doesn't work. Had I been in a "sane" environment, maybe I would get an error and a stack trace. Or maybe I could use a debugger. Or maybe `%{REQUEST_URI}` would have been a variable, and I could print it in a console, and not use deductive reasoning to figure out what it may, or may not contain.

How is it possible to find out what steps follow when a url I've entered in my browser passes through `.htaccess`?

Comment: What about apache/mod_rewrite is *not* sane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled the rewrite log? It's right in [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog).

```
RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

At that log level, it will be **very** verbose, but hopefully you will be able to find the data you need.

Comment: You mean I need to add these lines to `.htaccess`? I did, and apache informed me of an `Internal Server Error`. I don't know whether it meant it couldn't parse `.htaccess`, or it didn't have permission to write to the specified file, or... I don't know.

Comment: You have to enable rewritelog in the configuration, not in .htaccess files. And if you have access to the server config there is no reason to have your rewriterules in .htaccess. Putting rewrite rules in .htaccess should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Yes, I've figured it out. It shows me all the strings involved in the rewrite, including variables. IOW, it's awesome, thanks. I have a local server with one subfolder per project. Using `.htaccess` files is easier. I know it's generally bad practice.